# Organize Subflows in palette

Tags: node-red

Background:
I am currently working on a project where we are using Node-RED as a tool to create a dynamic program flow. This flow consists of sequences that include subsequences which in turn consist of sub-subsequences. all of them can be used multiple times within the flow. I therefore am using subflows nested in subflows. Unfortunately there is no way around using three different layers. That's a project specification. While I think this isn't exactly how Node-RED is meant to be used, it works like it should.

Problem:
Since I am using lots of subflows, my palette in the editor is filled with them. I figured the only way to tell them apart is to name them so I know which 'layer' they belong to. Main, sub or sub-sub. However, that way the palette looks very cluttered. The only way I found to get around that is by filtering the nodes. That's not very convenient though.

Question:
Is there a way to automatically sort the subflows into different categories by parsing the name? So they'd be in three different categories - Main, sub and sub-sub - instead of all sharing the subflow category? I'd be open to other solutions as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is a single subflow category and no further organisation is possible.

We've recognised the need for some better organisation options, but it isn't something that has had any really thought or discussion.

If you wanted to discuss this as a feature request on the project, I suggest you follow up on the project [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red).